# Getting Magit to Show Word Count Diff

Tags: magit, diff, words

I'm aware that by setting

```
(setq magit-diff-refine-hunk 'all)
```

we can get magit to show the words added/changed:

> [image]

**Question:** Is there a way to force the display the *total number of words added*, *total number of words removed*, and *net words changed*?  Similar to the way git shows this (but with lines), on every commit? So here the desired result would the display of `+7 words added, -1 word removed, +8 net words changed`, or something like that.

Comment: Magit does not include such option. Do you know a way how to achieve it with git? Do you urgently need a solution?

Comment: I don't know how to achieve this with git either. A solution is desired, but not urgent :)

Comment: Well, you could start a terminal from the diff buffer and use the solution provided in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2874426/6837095) (using external wdiff via the python script), it is a very easy solution. I have tested it, and it works fine (luckily magit ignores that 'global git config').